# How to implement a binary to ascii conversion? (and vice versa)

Tags: java, ascii, binaryfiles, binary-data

I want to write two simple utilities:

1. Receives a Binary file, and converts it to a text file (ASCII format).
2. Receives a text file in the format of the above file and restores the original binary file.

The reason I need this is that very stupid, but still a reason. I have two computers - one with internet access and one without. I write software on the one without internet. I get emails on the 2nd one. I need to transfer binary files from one to another (e.g. jars) but the only communication between them is a clipboard (text only).

Might be a very localized problem - but I assume it has some solution in the worlds of data encryption/compression/network transfer.

The only thing I could come up is go over the binary file and convert each byte into it's HEX representation - so for every byte I'll get two ASCII characters (i.e. two bytes). Is there anything better? (This solution doubles the amount of info and might not be possible to transfer via clipboard)

One limitation - I need it as a java based solution (I want to write it myself)

Comment: And for what sins The Witch has crippled your setup like this? o_O

Comment: Company wide policy - I'm just doing my duty as an employee to find a back door ...

Comment: How does this clipboard work? If it's over some kind of network, perhaps it would work better if you hijacked that connection.

Comment: How exactly are they connected that the one computer without internet can access another computer's clipboard.  I have never seen that done before.  You have no other way of transfering files what does everyone else do?

Comment: Also, I recommend a flash drive.

Comment: The two computers are only connectable via remote desktop. The internet one is a virtual one (VM Ware's VDM I think). So I assume that is how they prevent the desktop from accessing the web. That is also how the clipboard works - because the Remote Desktop Connection supports it (and it was not blocked).

So flashdrive is not an option (seriously - I'm not that dumb :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google for Base64, and use Apache commons codec to have a ready to use implementation.

Comment: Can you please add some more details? What does 'Google for Base64' mean?

Comment: You're looking to read in a binary file and base64 encode it.  This encodes all of the content of the base64 file as text (64 different characters' worth).  This is copyable.  On the other end, base64 decode it back into binary.

Comment: @Ronk: To google : the action of using a web browser and use Google to search for something. Base64 is a way to encode binary data in ASCII. 4 chars are needed to encode 3 bytes of binary data, which is more efficient than Hex encoding. Apache commons codec has an implementation of this encoding/decoding algorithm.